# How to make horizontal division using html div tag and css

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

I'm trying to make two horizontal divisons using `<div>` tag in html, but I couldn't make it. Can anyone help me make horizontal division using html and css with `<div>` tags?

[image: This is prototype]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `float` property for each `div` to be matched, for example `left` to each, give each of them enough width so that the parent contains them.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cwgv4/)

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="firstDivistion" class="division"></div>
<div id="secondDivistion" class="division"></div>


.division{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
`<div style='float:left'>stuffs</div>
<div style='float:right'>stuffs</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>`
```

Works well in every cases and is followed in many places...