# how do I give partition in the <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS. I want to divide my `div` using CSS. I want my page to have a top bar with only three links, with a large amount of space in between the links. My problem is that I am unsure of how to get the space in between the links. Can this be done without using tables?

```
         Home                     About                      Songlist
```

Comment: Use some margin-left / padding-left / width 33% on each div division / ...

Comment: Have a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349109/how-to-make-horizontal-division-using-html-div-tag-and-css

Comment: while the answers below will work, and are useful for learning, you will eventually find that this sort of thing is best solved in a reusable (very important!) fashion using a grid system (I recommend http://gridpak.com/), and in the near future using flexbox (excellent article by Bocoup Group: http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/). Good luck with the learning - it never gets boring! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Steve's answer, but here is another way using 3 separate Div's to achieve the same result.

HTML:

```
<div class="example">
    <a href="">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="example">
    <a href="">About</a>
</div>
<div class="example">
    <a href="">Songlist</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example
{
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    background: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwbuZ/) for reference.

Best of luck with whichever path you choose!

Answer (score 4):

Here is mark-up for the layout you describe (without all the style - just the layout)...

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/songs">Songlist</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS

```
ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}

ul.menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to include `box-sizing:border-box;` in there as well. That will prevent any `padding`/`margin` from screwing up the layout

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align: justify;` on the container element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kSmus/1/)**

### MARKUP

```
<div class="container">
<div class="example">
    <a href="">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="example">
    <a href="">About</a>
</div>
<div class="example">
    <a href="">Songlist</a>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 50px;
    background: aqua;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.example {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain as to how the content : " "  is doing the magic ? Thanks a lot. Please edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `float` css property, combined with margin / padding or width. The float idea is a bit tricky in the beginning, but will become second nature pretty soon.

Also, as commented, you should think about using `<ul>` and `<li>` HTML tags.

[A tutorial for float](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/)

Comment: Inline block is also a good solution. Anyway, if you are a begginer, you should practice your "float muscle"

Comment: @Giliweed if you float them all `left` they will stack up as you need - although you will need to handle the content that follows as `float` takes the elements out of the document flow. `inline-block` preserves the document flow.

Comment: is there any css property , "float:middle;"  ?  just asking even though I got my solution.

Comment: The way float works is to make elements appear one after the other horizontally. If you use float left for three elements, the first one will be on the left end, the second one in the middle, and the third one in the right end. If you use float: right - the order will be reversed